# Is number of compiled modules affecting size of linux kernel in RAM?

Tags: linux-kernel

When I am compiling a Linux kernel, the amount of drivers and modules I compile is definitely affecting the size of produced binary. But does it also affect the size of kernel when it loads into memory?

I mean, when I compile drivers that I don't need for my hardware, will the kernel just ignore them, or are they also loaded in RAM?

**TL;DR :

I compile kernel A containing ONLY drivers that I need;

Kernel B containing drivers I need + extra drivers I don't.

Will kernel B eat more memory than kernel A?**

Comment: Yes. If the drivers are built as part of the kernel image. No if they are built as kernel `ko` modules and not loaded unless required.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: Can you submit this as an answer? Some references would be nice as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Any driver that is built as part of the Linux kernel image is loaded into main memory during boot and will continue to consume main memory irrespective of whether it is used.
2. Drivers built as separate modules i.e. **`.ko`** files can be separately loaded as required. They do NOT consume any main memory unless they are loaded.

   - Loading a kernel module is done using [`modprobe`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/modprobe) and [`insmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/insmod) commands, after the Linux kernel is loaded and running.
   - When loading a Linux kernel *module* using `modprobe`, any other modules *it* depends upon are [automatically loaded first](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/x197.html#INTELLIGENT).
   - When the kernel modules are loaded, they need to be mapped into a contiguous block of virtual memory. This is achieved by introducing an [additional constraint on the memory map using `vmalloc`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Module-HOWTO/#MEMALLOC).